# What does "OFF" mean in a script?

Tags: screenwriting, script, dramatic-writing

Could anybody, please, enlighten me as to what "off" means in the following excerpts taken from the script for the TV show "Breaking Bad"? (I've also come across the same use of "off" in other scripts).

> "Our two scary Cousins glare at Heisenberg. Off them, wrathful and
>   unblinking, their lips moving in silent prayer... and us thinking ”Oh
>   shit. THIS can’t be good...”
>
> He stands chest-high, frantically splashing water at the last few
>   lumps of cash still BURNING poolside. Off our hero...
>
> PAMELA Alright. I usually open with “So sorry you’re here...” (off
>   Sky’s sad smile) Where would you like to begin?
>
> PAMELA And it’s not an apartment, it’s a house that you live in? (off
>   Skyler’s nod) Do you own outright, or is there a mortgage, or do you
>
> SKYLER Okay. I will think about that. **Off the two of them shaking
>   hand**s -- friendly, but strained
>
> Off Walt, staring at him... then lowering his head in assent:
>
> Off her, frustrated and grieving and not allowed by circumstance to
>   even explain herself to her son...
>
> The two slices are carefully mated. Off come the crusts, sliced with a
>   sharp knife.
>
> Off come their Canali suits.
>
> Off these strange events...
>
> MARIE He must have! Why not just say it?! -- Off Marie, left stewing
>   now
>
> Off Jesse, maybe just now beginning to see the light...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context you've provided, `OFF Marie, left stewing now` means "this is the last thing the camera sees before it moves *off* her to the next shot."

These are framing directions to the camera person. Look at the parentheticals:

> PAMELA And it’s not an apartment, it’s a house that you live in? `(off Skyler’s nod)` Do you own outright, or is there a mortgage, or do you...

That means that while Pamela is speaking, the camera either cuts to Skyler so the audience can see her nodding or the camera has been focusing on Skyler while Pamela is speaking out of the frame and then cuts (back) to Pamela with Skyler's nod.

Comment: and what about this line with Jesse? @LaurenIpsum

Comment: "Off Jesse, maybe just now beginning to see the light..." means that the camera lingers on Jesse's face for five seconds so we can see and understand his expression, and then changes to a new scene. Again, it's an editing/camera direction to indicate "this is the last visual before the next beat."

Comment: You can find both the script (Breaking Bad, S03E01 "No Mas") and the video online and compare what is described in the script to what happens in the filmed episode. There are some discrepancies, but many of the "off"s are in there.

Answer (score 0):

In a screenplay, "Off" is an abbreviation for "off-screen" or "off-stage" or "off-camera". Thus, whatever actions are happening, are happening off camera.

Look here for basics on the terms used while writing a screenplay/stageplay/etc.: http://www.screenwriting.info/glossary.php

Comment: Off Jesse, maybe just now beginning to see the light... - then, how are we, the audience, to understand that Jesse is beginning to see the light if that's what happens to him OFF camera.. it just doesn't make sense to me.. @PraveshParekh

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're completely misinterpreting this "off." The glossary you link to specifically punctuates it as (off). That *does* mean "offscreen" or "offstage." This one doesn't.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum What I meant to say was by saying off camera was that these are directions for the cameraman. For example, something that is off might be happening when it is not the centre of focus of the camera. Is that a wrong interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that is a wrong interpretation in this context. Something happening "out of frame" (so, not visible) might be marked as (off). For example: *JOHN: How about we take this case? SHERLOCK (off): Bo-ring.* In that line, (off) indicates that what we see (what is on-camera) is only John. Sherlock is speaking, in some other part of the room, and we *hear* him, but he is "off-camera," so we don't see him.

Comment: But compare: *JOHN: Looked you up online last night. SHERLOCK: And? (off John's expression) What?* In this case, Sherlock speaks, the camera shifts to focus on John, we *see* John make a face -- although he doesn't speak -- and then the direction is for the camera to *leave John's face as the last moment in the beat* and shift to Sherlock's next word, which is his reaction to John's expression. The scriptwriter is giving direction to the camera without giving Sherlock a new line.

Comment: You could also write that second example this way: *JOHN: Looked you up online last night. SHERLOCK: And? JOHN: (makes a you-have-to-be-kidding-me face) SHERLOCK: What?* This exactly the same result, just making the expression more explicit, although it does not give camera direction.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Thanks for the clarification. I see now. Should I retract my answer or do I leave it here for other users who might be interested in your clarification? (I am inclined for the latter)

Comment: Leave it. No need to scrub history. We learn from mistakes too. :)